# Overlay.of(context) is called on null

Tags: flutter, navigation, overlay

So i want this overlay widget to be present in all the pages and dont want to be disturbed during the transition between pages, it throws this Exception and the overlay widget is not built, what am i doing wrong here?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);

    return MaterialApp(
        color: Colors.white,
        title: 'Gratitude',
        navigatorKey: AppNavigator.navigatorKey,
        onGenerateRoute: AppNavigator.onGenerateRoute,
        theme: ThemeData(
            fontFamily: AppFonts.POPPINS,
            textTheme: theme.textTheme.apply(
              fontFamily: AppFonts.POPPINS,
              displayColor: AppColors.TEXT_COLOR,
            )),
        builder: (context, child) {
          final data = MediaQuery.of(context);
          final smallestSize = min(data.size.width, data.size.height);
          final textScaleFactor =
              min(smallestSize / AppConstants.designScreenSize.width, 1.0);
          return MediaQuery(
              data: data.copyWith(textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor),
              child: Builder(
                builder: (context) {
                  WidgetsBinding.instance
                      .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _insertOverlay(context));
                  return child;
                },
              ));
        });
  }

  void _insertOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    return Overlay.of(context).insert(
      OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
        final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        print(size.width);
        return Positioned(
          width: 56,
          height: 56,
          top: size.height - 72,
          left: size.width - 72,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => print('ON TAP OVERLAY!'),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.redAccent),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

error

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during a scheduler callback:
The method 'insert' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: insert(Instance of 'OverlayEntry')

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      MyApp._insertOverlay (package:bbs_mobile/main.dart:49:32)
#2      MyApp.build... (package:bbs_mobile/main.dart:41:48)
#3      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#4      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1090:9)
#5      SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame. (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:865:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)

Comment: `_insertOverlay` uses wrong context - you need a context from a `Scaffold` for example, not `MaterialApp`

Comment: But i want the overlay to be on top of navigator, so that its common between all the pages

Comment: it will be on top of `Navigator`

Comment: if im using scaffold it will be available for that particular page ryt? i want it to be common for all pages and shouldnt fade during page transition

Comment: it will be always visible, no matter what page you are on

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that `Overlay.of(context)` requires a context from a parent Widget like a [Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html).

Alternatively, you can utilize Navigator to retain the same screen objects. But remember that screen navigation in Flutter rebuilds the screen so the Widgets will be rebuilt again. Here's an [example](https://github.com/omatt/flutter-navdrawer-template/blob/main/lib/main.dart) of this approach that I've done before.